# HTML/CSS making a mouse over button to display footer

Tags: html, css, button, footer

So for my project I've setup a fixed header and footer but noticed that my footer is rather large. What I'd like to do is hide it and add a button toward the bottom that when you hover over will display the whole footer.

Here is my current website: http://webcomp41.volume11.com/final/index.html

How would I go about adding this feature? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS Solution:** (show/hide completely)

for it to work, you just need to make the button and the footer siblings

```
#footer
{
  display: none;
}
#button:hover ~ #footer
{
  display: block;
}
```

you can use the same technique to specify different size instead of show/hide.

and as Ali Sheikhpour said:
notice: replace the word "button" with the ID of button and "footer" with the ID of footer.

Example [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/weowrkhh/)

Answer (score 0):

jquery solution:

```
$("#button").hover(function(){$("#footer").show()})
```

notice: replace the word "button" with the ID of button and "footer" with the ID of footer.